# How to deal with Header dependencies in C (ffmpeg) library?

Tags: c, ffmpeg, dependencies, header-files

I am trying to call functions directly from FFMPEG. I have run the Makefile for FFMPEG successfully. Here is my setup:

/FFMPEG
/MySimpleProject

Inside my simple project I have

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "../ffmpeg/libavformat/avformat.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    av_register_all();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

But when I try to compile this with `cc main.c` I get:

```
In file included from main.c:3:
./../ffmpeg/libavformat/avformat.h:319:10: fatal error: 
'libavcodec/avcodec.h' file not found
```

The reason I get this is because the `#include`s in FFMPEG look like this:

```
#include "libavcodec/avcodec.h"
...
```

which does not reflect the actual file structure. The relative path would be `#include "../libavcodec/avcodec.h"` and when I do this, the compiler errors out on the next dependency. How do I resolve this dependency craziness? There must be some setting within FFMPEG that even allows them to omit the relative paths.

Comment: Based on your paths, put `-I../ffmpeg` in the include path compiler switches, and use `#include "libavformat/avformat.h"` in your project.

Comment: @WhozCraig Awesome! That worked. Sorry to double up on your here, but now I receive:  Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64. This is sort of the same question because I can include the object file where that method lives, but then there are other things in that file the compiler doesnt know about. Dependency craziness all over again!

Comment: Undefined symbols and/or references is a link-time error. It means you're not linking the ffmpeg library(s) appropriate for your chosen architecture build (or at all). Depending on whether your building x86 or x64, the path to the libs must be provided to the linker, and the appropriate .so and/or .a files must be added to your link line's lib list.